# Material UI Drawer won't move under Appbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an Appbar and a drawer right beneath it. Under both components I have 3 `divs` with bootstrap and in each `div` I have a group of buttons.

The problem is that the Drawer covers the Appbar and I just can't seem to move it.

Here's my code:

```
<div className="App">

        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
              <IconButton color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                title
              </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          style={{width: '100%', zIndex: '1400', position:'absolute'}}
        >
          <Button>1</Button>
          <Button>2</Button>
          <Divider />
          <Button>1</Button>
          <Button>2</Button>
        </Drawer>
        <br />
        <div className="container-full">
          <div className="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">  
              <GridList cellHeight={50} className={styles.gridList} cols={5}>

                <Button style={{width: '150px', border: '1px solid'}} variant="raised" color="primary">
                  <div 
                  style={{fontSize:'12px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', textAlign:'center'}}>
                    Mohnweckerl Wiener Gouda
                  </div>
                </Button>
```

After the first bootstrap column, another `"col-sm-4"` follows and then a `"col-sm-2"`. The buttons are in a `GridList`

Here's a visual

[image]

The Drawer should start where the arrows meet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to make the z-index of the drawer less than the z-index of the app bar (you'll probably need to use `!important` for it to have any effect). You'll need to add padding of 56px to the top of the drawer as well.

Comment: If I add `paddingTop:56` or `padding:56`to the drawer, it just pushes my buttons down. The drawer stays as it is.

Comment: Right, so you will also need to either increase the z-index of the navigation bar, or decrease the z-index of the drawer. ie, say you want to increase the z-index of the navigation bar. you can use `z-index: 24 !important;`

Comment: `<AppBar position="absolute" style={{zIndex: 24}}>` and the drawer inline `style={{position:'relative', zIndex: 1, paddingTop:'56px !important'}}` - looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/nWtlM)

Comment: edit: Sorry, I misread your comment. Let me look into it real quick

Comment: Np. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/Wfe17xAq) my code. Ignore all the useless buttons.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Material-UI docs call that a Drawer that's been [clipped under the app bar](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar). To achieve it, you first have to define a `z-index` for your `AppBar` your `styles` object:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  appBar: {
    // Make the app bar z-index always one more than the drawer z-index
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
});
```

And then apply that to the `AppBar` component:

```
<AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.appBar}>
```

Since your drawer is now underneath the `AppBar`, you'll need to move the content in the drawer down the screen so that it is not hidden underneath the bar. You can accomplish that with `theme.mixins.toolbar`. First, add the `toolbar` styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  // Loads information about the app bar, including app bar height
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
});
```

Then, add the following `div` as the very first piece of content in your drawer:

```
<Drawer>
  // Make sure this div is the first piece of content in your drawer
  <div className={classes.toolbar} />

  // Put your other drawer content here like you normally would
</Drawer>
```

The `toolbar` style will load information about the app bar height from the current `theme` and then size the `div` so that it ensures the content doesn't get hidden by the app bar.

You can find a full code sample [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/pages/demos/drawers/ClippedDrawer.js).

Comment: Now it looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/5CDlu).`<AppBar position="absolute" style={{zIndex: 2}}` and the drawer `style={{position:'relative', zIndex: 1}} variant="permanent"` The buttons got behind the drawer, but I solved it with `paddingLeft:100`and `paddingRight:100`.

Comment: Right - that's because you're hard-coding a z-index for the drawer without editing the z-index for the buttons. Using the z-index value from the theme avoids that problem by making sure that the all of the depths are correct in relation to one another.

Comment: So all three components need a different zIndex, right? The Appbar's zIndex is `theme.zIndex.drawer + 1` the Drawer's is 2 and the the `<div>` where the buttons are gets 4. Somehow the buttons still get pushed down and the Drawer won't move. Also I cannot access `classes` in `className={classes.appBar}`, only `styles.appBar`.

Comment: You only need to change the z-index of the app bar to be one higher than the drawer. Everything else (like the buttons) should adjust automatically. As to your problem with classes...what version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: The version is `"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.35"`.

I set appbar's zIndex to drawer+1 and used paddingTop to push it down but it still looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/vKT3N).

Here's the inline `style={{zIndex: 'theme.zIndex.drawer + 1'}}`

Comment: Idk why the imgur pic is black - [here's](https://imgur.com/a/ibBQ4) another link

Comment: You're not going to be able to accomplish this with inline styles because you only have access to the `theme` object when using [CSS-in-JS](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/). You'll need to use the `className={classes.appBar}` [construct with `withStyles`](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component).

Comment: Oh, damn. I totally overlooked `theme`. React couldn't find `classes` when I used `className={classes.appBar}` so what I did was `className={this.props.classes.appBar}`. Somehow I still can't push down the drawer.The buttons are getting pushed down instead. Tried to change their zIndex but it didn't help. I'm using `paddingTop: 56` in `styles`

Comment: I just added `paddingTop` to the first button in the `drawer` and it pushed all the buttons down. Seems more like a workaround though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "push down the buttons". Do you mean moving them vertically down the screen? Or pushing down their elevation?

Comment: Sorry, I meant moving them vertically downwards.

Comment: So the buttons added to the drawer should start where the Appbar ends.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a way that's a bit better than `paddingTop`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Mhh strange, the upper button shows only if I scroll down, but maybe I am not using the component as intended. I decided to change that part of the UI, nevertheless I will mark your answer as the thread answer. Thanks for taking your time, I didn't know about `zIndex` before.

I still have to figure out why I can't use `className={classes.appBar}`. `classes` is apparently undefined. `className={this.props.classes.appBar}` works though.

Comment: As you have correctly deduced `classes` comes from the `props`. I usually do something like `const { classes } = this.props` at the top of each `render` method. You can see that in the full code sample as well.

Comment: I'm declaring my component as `class A extends Component` instead of `function A(props)...` so I'm still getting an undefined for `classes` if I declare `classes` as `const` after `render()`. Also it kind of behaves differently than an inline `style={{...}}` tbh.

Comment: If you're `extending Component` then it just has to be `const { classes } = this.props` (note the `this.`).

Answer (score 0):

In MUI v5, the [default `zIndex` values are](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/#explore):

```js
const zIndex = {
  mobileStepper: 1000,
  fab: 1050,
  speedDial: 1050,
  appBar: 1100,
  drawer: 1200,
  modal: 1300,
  snackbar: 1400,
  tooltip: 1500,
};
```

Which explains why the drawer covers the appBar.

Another solution using [ThemeProvider](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-provider) that simply swaps these values (Typescript):

```
// ./theme/index.tsx

import {
  ThemeProvider as MUIThemeProvider,
  createTheme,
} from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface ThemeProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: ThemeProviderProps) => {
  const theme = createTheme({ zIndex: { appBar: 1200, drawer: 1100 } });
  return (
    <MUIThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {children}
    </MUIThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

```js
// ./App.tsx

import { ThemeProvider } from "./theme";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider>
        // your component(s)
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```